# PHP HTMLPurifier AutoParagraph with single newline

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

On my website I have comment boxes. I format comments with htmlpurifier.

Right now, if a user wants to create 2 distinct lines (2 `<p>` tags in the end), they have to type something like this:

```
test line 1

test line 2
```

which in PHP will be stored like this:

```
test line 1\n
\n
test line 2
```

This will create two distinct `<p>` paragraphs because I have AutoParagraph turned on (http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#AutoFormat.AutoParagraph). This only happens when it detects 2 linebreaks, as it states in the documentation.

However, what I want is for users to also be able to create 2 distinct paragraphs with a single line break, for example an input like this:

```
test line 1
test line 2
```

How can I make this happen? Maybe I should double the amount of line breaks in the string before running it through htmlpurifier?

Comment: Use PHP_EOL instead of \n